# how execute multiple onEdit commands for separate google sheet Drop downs where I need to make multiple selections in each drop down

Tags: google-apps-script

I am attempting to create 2 separate drop down menus that allow for multiple selections in each one on the same gs, this is what I have so far (I will preface I am a self taught coder and still learning, so any answer in detailed step bystep would be much appreciated :)....)

```
function onEdit(e){
}
var oldValue;
var newValue;
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
if(activeCell.getColumn() == 18 && ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="IS WORKSPACE_ALL") {
newValue=e.value;
oldValue=e.oldValue;
if(!e.value) {
activeCell.setValue("");
}
else {
if (!e.oldValue) {
activeCell.setValue(newValue);
}
else {
activeCell.setValue(oldValue+', '+newValue) return;
}
}
}
}
function onEdit(e){
}
var oldValue;
var newValue;
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
if(activeCell.getColumn() == 22 && ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="IS WORKSPACE_ALL") {
newValue=e.value;
oldValue=e.oldValue;
if(!e.value) {
activeCell.setValue("");
}
else {
if (!e.oldValue) {
activeCell.setValue(newValue);
}
else {
activeCell.setValue(oldValue+', '+newValue) return;
}
}
}
}

When I go back to the spreadsheet only one of the commands is executing and I need both to work please 


This questions is referencing Column R and Column V in the attached document

I have tried the following:

function onEdit(e){
}
var oldValue;
var newValue;
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
if(activeCell.getColumn() == 18 && ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="IS WORKSPACE_ALL") {
newValue=e.value;
oldValue=e.oldValue;
if(!e.value) {
activeCell.setValue("");
}
else {
if (!e.oldValue) {
activeCell.setValue(newValue);
}
else {
activeCell.setValue(oldValue+', '+newValue) return;
}
}
}
}
function onEdit(e){
}
var oldValue;
var newValue;
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
if(activeCell.getColumn() == 22 && ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="IS WORKSPACE_ALL") {
newValue=e.value;
oldValue=e.oldValue;
if(!e.value) {
activeCell.setValue("");
}
else {
if (!e.oldValue) {
activeCell.setValue(newValue);
}
else {
activeCell.setValue(oldValue+', '+newValue) return;
}
}
}
}

AND:
```

```
``
function onEdit(e) }
onEdit1(e);
onEdit29e);
}

function onEdit1(e){
}
var oldValue;
var newValue;
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
if(activeCell.getColumn() == 18 && ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="IS WORKSPACE_ALL") {
newValue=e.value;
oldValue=e.oldValue;
if(!e.value) {
activeCell.setValue("");
}
else {
if (!e.oldValue) {
activeCell.setValue(newValue);
}
else {
activeCell.setValue(oldValue+', '+newValue) return;
}
}
}
}
function onEdit2(e){
}
var oldValue;
var newValue;
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
if(activeCell.getColumn() == 22 && ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="IS WORKSPACE_ALL") {
newValue=e.value;
oldValue=e.oldValue;
if(!e.value) {
activeCell.setValue("");
}
else {
if (!e.oldValue) {
activeCell.setValue(newValue);
}
else {
activeCell.setValue(oldValue+', '+newValue) return;
}
}
}
}

``
```

AND

//running on in separate files.

This questions is referencing Column R and Column V in the below images'
[[[Snapshots of sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17t6T.png)][(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtlZg.png)](https://stackoverflow.com)]`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbUGY.png)`

Comment: You can have multiple function that use the onEdit trigger.  But only one of them can be named onEdit() the other one must be an installable trigger and it must have a unique name like all other functions

Comment: @Cooper thank you for the information - thats what I figured but have no idea what those triggers would be  - would you be able to illustrate what that code would look like?  Appreciate the help!

Comment: They would be [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) onEdit triggers